# Mock File class and NullPointerException

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I'm creating a File mock object with Mockito that will be used as the directory to store a new  File.

```
Folder folder = Mockito.mock(File.class);
File file = new Agent().createNewFile(folder, "fileName");
```

and inside my Agent class:

```
public File createNewFile(File folder, String filename){
    return new File(folder, "testfile");
}
```

But I'm getting a NullPointerException at the initialization block of File when creating the new file inside `createNewFile` method:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:308)
```

I think it happens because File doesn't have any empty constructor, so when mocking the object some internal state remains null.

Am I taking the wrong approach mocking the `File folder` object? My goal is to check some constraints before creating the new file, but I don't want to depend on an existing real folder on the file system.

Thank you.

Comment: "I think it happens because File doesn't have any empty constructor"

I'm not familiar with Mockito but that is most likely the case. The absence of a constructor with parameters sort of makes sense as the javadoc states that File is "An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames". As such, File would need to point a given file on the host system but doesn't represent it "physically" and simply allows to carry out file I/O operations.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to define the behavior for getPath() for folder as it gets called internally in File class.

You can do it as:

```
File folder = Mockito.mock(File.class);
when(folder.getPath()).thenReturn("C:\temp\");
File file = new Agent().createNewFile(folder, "fileName");
```

It will work only till you don't really create a new file but only calling new File.

Comment: I do not believe this solves the problem, at least not for me, the code in File(File parent, String child) constructor blows up because the path attribute is null, "if (parent.path.equals("")) {"...

Comment: I too don't understand how this would solve the problem.
After all you don't get further then line 1 in the code you post as an example. The nullpointer is thrown right there.

Comment: Agree this does not answer the question for JDK 7u40 and up due to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8003992 which modified FileInputStream to call File.isInvalid() in its ctor and File.isInvalid() accesses the File.path member variable directly rather than File.getPath().